# Displaying Data Based on Ternary Operator in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I need either `annualPlans` or `monthlyPlans` to map it depending if `isAnually` is true or not. and what is the safest way to put in the price?
I have a toggle button by the way which switches between the annualPlans and monthlyPlans.

How do it do it?

Here's my code below

```
{isAnnually
  ? annualPlans
  : monthlyPlans.map((p, index) => (
      <Fragment key={index}>
        <PlanCard
          id={p.value}
          current={p.current}
          title={p.name}
          price={`$ ${
           p.annual_price ? p.annual_price : p.monthly_price
           }`}
        />
      </Fragment>
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap your ternary condition in parenthesis before you call `.map()`.

```
{(isAnnually ? annualPlans : monthlyPlans).map((p, index) => (
  <Fragment key={index}>
    <PlanCard
      id={p.value}
      current={p.current}
      title={p.name}
    />
  </Fragment>
))}
```